# Graph View Libraries - GraphViewData not found

Tags: android, graph

I was trying to find a good library to use for an android graph. I have looked at links such as this one: http://www.achartengine.org/index.html
Here there were multiple errors in the example file, Eclipse couldn't find some packages and things like that.
The other one I tried is android plot, but it appears to be broken.

Now I am trying to use Graph View from here: http://www.jjoe64.com/2011/07/chart-and-graph-library-for-android.html
And I am trying to run an example program but now eclipse can't find GraphViewData. Can anyone help me please? I stuck the example program into onCreate in my Activity and imported the files that Eclipse could find. I am also open to other graph suggestions that work.

Comment: Try achartengine again, if you get errors please post specific information about the errors so that we can help you.

Comment: Just tried it again. It tells me: [2012-06-25 21:22:58 - AChartEngineDemo] Unable to resolve target 'android-7'
And then it can't find java.io packages, which normally are no problem, nor can it find "org.achartengine.chartdemo.demo.R". These errors start in XYChartBuilder.java, but if I remove that file, the same type of errors appear in the next file - WeightDialChart
Do I not have something proper installed?

Comment: Did you add the library to your project build path?

Comment: Yes. But now I found the problem solution here: https://groups.google.com/forum/?fromgroups#!topic/achartengine/TLHv3a08GdA

Comment: glad you got it working. Can you post an answer here that explains what you did to get it working. Then after a few days accept your own answer as correct. By doing so you'll help people in the future to solve this problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Apparently, this is a common problem and is resolved by the following steps:

In Eclipse:

- Right click your project - go to build path - select Configure build path
- go to the "Order and Export" tab
- Check the "achartengine-1.0.0.jar box and then single click its name
- move it up so its right below the Android dependancies (sometimes this can make a difference if you have multiple Jars)

click ok then clean your project. (Project -> Clean...)

Source: https://groups.google.com/forum/?fromgroups#!topic/achartengine/TLHv3a08GdA

Edit:
Similar solution works for GraphView as well!

Comment: The issue is about     implementation group: 'com.jjoe64', name: 'graphview', version: '4.2.2' chartlibrary.verstion 4.2.2 compared to its old overstion 3.1.4

Comment: Why the downvote? This resolved my problem (and I am the one who asked the question). Perhaps it's outdated now since people no longer use Eclipse, but the question itself is also outdated.

Answer (score 10):

GraphViewData is not a built-in class. It is just an example of any class implementing the GraphViewDataInterface. If you look carefully you will notice that the signature of the GraphViewSeries constructor says that it takes an array of GraphViewDataInterface objects (i.e. objects of any class implementing the GraphViewDataInterface). I know this is not explicitly written in the simple graph example found at http://android-graphview.org/#doc_createsimplegraph but it is the truth.

Simply, create a class named GraphViewData(or use any other name) that implements GraphViewDataInterface and use it as follows.

- Add the following class to your project:

  ```
  public class GraphViewData implements GraphViewDataInterface {
      private double x,y;

      public GraphViewData(double x, double y) {
          this.x = x;
          this.y = y;
      }

      @Override
      public double getX() {
          return this.x;
      }

      @Override
      public double getY() {
          return this.y;
      }
  }
  ```
- Now use it:

  ```
  GraphViewSeries exampleSeries = new GraphViewSeries(new GraphViewData[] {
      new GraphViewData(1, 2.0d),
      new GraphViewData(2, 1.5d),
      new GraphViewData(3, 2.5d),
      new GraphViewData(4, 1.0d),
      new GraphViewData(5, 3.0d),
      new GraphViewData(6, 4.75d)
  });
  ```

I hope that will help.
Thank You.

Comment: GraphViewDataInterface not found ._.

Answer (score 5):

You don't have to create your own GraphViewData.
GraphViewData appears to be a public static inner class of GraphView.

You can simply import it by doing:

```
import com.jjoe64.graphview.GraphView.GraphViewData;
```

Hope this helps anyone else

Update: This was tested against GraphView-3.1.3

Comment: @berserk 

What is not working for you ? What notification are you getting ?
Which version of the jar are you using ? 

I tested this with GraphView-3.1.3.jar

Comment: I just downloaded the full src of library from server. And was unable to find this class. Now I copied the 3.1.1 version jar. And I can see the class now.

Answer (score 2):

you can import in **gradle**

```
 compile 'com.jjoe64:graphview:3.1.3'
```